# How do I call ReactJS class component and functional component from normal Javascript function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to call a ReactJS function ( functional Component ) from the normal JavaScript function. Its not printing the output because ReactJS uses the JSX syntax. Is it possible to call ReactJS functional component from the normal JS fucntion ? My Example code is here :

```
class Extra extends React.Component { 
      //This is the ReactJS class component 
}

function Greeting() {
       // This is the ReactJS functional component
      // I wanted to call this ReactJS functional component from the 
      normal JavaScript function 

      return (<Extra/>);
}

function Calling() {
    // This  is normal JavaScript function  which I have defined in the 
     separate file. From this function I wanted to call the ReactJS 
     function.

     Greeting();
}
```

I tried this. I called ReactJS functional component from the normal JS function. It is going inside the ReactJS function but its not displaying the JSX code on the browser ( JSX sytax of the ReactJS Class component)

Thanks in advance

Comment: please mention code understanding the problem

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58622028/edit) instead of posting code in the comments. It's hard to read. Please also use the ` tags around it to format it as code.

Comment: I have posted the code now. So, please go through it .

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can call Component class function from normal javascript function, but you need to make that react function **static** then call from noraml javascript by className.react_function()

Comment: Can u please give me the example . I am new to this ReactJS and JavaScript so, I didn't get you clearly. Can u please take my example  above and show me.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Extra extends React.Component { 
  //This is the ReactJS class component 

  static Greeting=()=>{
    console.log("Greeting from react class function");
  }
}


function Calling() {
  // This  is normal JavaScript function  which I have defined in the  separate file.From this function I wanted to call the ReactJS function.
 Extra.Greeting();
}
```

Comment: If you want to call from separate file you must include that "Extra" react class in this separate file  like import Extend from '{path_to_that_file}';

Comment: See my sequence of calling functions is .. I wanted to call my React Class component (Extra) from the React functional component ( Greeting() ) So, my React component should be outside of the Class component then after I have to call this React functional component from the normal JavaScript function.

Comment: I should be called as i tell

Comment: Thank you. I will try that :)